How can I modify the data returned by WebSocket to plaintext
How can I modify the data returned by WebSocket to plaintext and use Protobuf decoding to keep getting an error decoding message
RangeError: index out of range: 13 + 485538840 > 1428
What should I do with 'at indexOutOfRange' (pages index index. js: 8403:10)
How can I modify the data returned by WebSocket to plaintext
